# How can i bind data to a dropdown in the gridview which is an EditItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I declared my template as follows

```
    <EditItemTemplate>  
               <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear" runat="server" DataSource='<%#GetYears() %>' DataTextField="year" DataValueField="year"></asp:DropDownList>  
           </EditItemTemplate>
```

I need to bind the data from the function i used GetYears() i don't know how to function it can any one help me

I need the data for example name  to be loaded in dropdown when i click on Edit of gridview is it the correct way or is there any best way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the code behind you can find dropdown using findcontrol method on the click of edit link and can bind easily.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an objectDatasource on the page and then set the datasourceid to that objectDataSource. Then you can create your POCO class
Look at this link for more info on objectdatasource
http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/objectdatasource.aspx

Comment: I am asking it to bind for dropdown which was inside gridview

Comment: This should work if you don't require any parameters, just change the DataSource='<%#GetYears() %>' tag in your combobox inside the templatefield to DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" where ObjectDataSource1 is your objectdatasource. Does your getYears() function need to input parameters? If so then I can't really think of another method